# Interact with section plane

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am creating a section plane like:

```
    this.viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Section")
    const SectionTool = this.viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Section")
    SectionTool.load()
    SectionTool.activate()
    SectionTool.tool.setSectionPlane(this.hitTest.face.normal, this.hitTest.point)

    const state = this.viewer.getState();
    this.viewer.restoreState(state);
```

This works pretty well, and I get the section plane. But I am not able to interact with this plane like when creating with UI buttons. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to make this possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why store the hitTest results, then restore the other aspects of states without the cutplanes (if they were captured in the saved states ...) and then restore the cutplanes programmatically from the hittest results ... something like:

```
const hitTest = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hitTestResult'))
delete state.cutplanes
viewer.restoreState(state)

 const SectionTool = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Section")
 SectionTool.activate()
 SectionTool.tool.setSectionPlane(hitTest.face.normal, hitTest.point)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan! Yes, the restoring of the state, in the end, was for sure a mistake that created issues for me. It seems to work as it should now.
I do however have some issues getting the correct normal from hitPoints, but i think that might be a different problem, so i will open another question about that and close this one. Thank you very much!